# Plot table objects with ggplot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I've got this data:

```
         No    Yes
Female  411   130
Male    435   124
```

which was created using the standard table command. Now with plot I can plot this as such:

`plot(table(df$gender, df$fraud))`

and it then outputs a 2x2 bar chart.

So my question is, how can I do this with ggplot2? Is there any way with out transforming the table-object to a data frame? I would do that, but it becomes a mess and you then need to rename column and row headers and it just becomes a mess for what is really a quite simple thing?

Comment: Does: `plot(table(df$gender, df$fraud))` actually return a mosaicplot right?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Something such as

```
ggplot(as.data.frame(table(df)), aes(x=gender, y = Freq, fill=fraud)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

gets a similar chart with a minimum amount of relabelling.

Comment: It would be helpful if there was an example of this that could be seen ( the plot ) and run ( the code )

Answer (score 5):

ggplot2 works with data frame, so, you have to convert table into a frame. Here is a sample code:

```
myTable <- table(df$gender, df$fraud)
myFrame <- as.data.frame(table(myTable))
```

Now, you can use myFrame in ggplot2:

```
ggplot(myFrame, aes(x=gender))+
  geom_bar(y = Freq)
```

see [Coerce to a Data Frame](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/as.data.frame.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, `janitor::tabyl()` outputs contingency tables that are data.frames. As such, they are more convenient for a workflow based on tidyverse tools.

For example:

```
# Data
df <- data.frame(gender = c(rep("female", times = 411),
                            rep("female", times = 130),
                            rep("male", times = 435),
                            rep("male", times = 124)),
                 fraud = c(rep("no", times = 411),
                           rep("yes", times = 130),
                           rep("no", times = 435),
                           rep("yes", times = 124)))

# Plotting the tabulation with tidyverse tools
df |> 
  janitor::tabyl(gender, fraud) |>
  tidyr::gather(key = fraud, value = how_many, no:yes) |>
  ggplot2::ggplot(aes(y = how_many, x = gender, fill = fraud)) +
  geom_col()
```

Note: The sequence of piped results with `janitor` and `tidyr` has the benefit of being more transparent, but it essentially replicates the same result achieved with `as.data.frame(table(df))`.