# How to create pattern table in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make a table like the one below in R. I am not sure what the table is called and packages that could do that in R.

# I would like the create the following table in R

[image: table graphic]

Below is what my data set looks like:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(ani=c("cat","dog","frog","fish","rat","snake","chicken"),
               year=c(2015,2016,2015,2018,2019,2017,2018),
               start_date=c("01-Jan-2015", "30-Mar-2016","08-Aug-2015",
                            "25-Nov-2018","05-Apr-2019","03-Mar-2017",
                            "11-Oct-2018"),
               end_date=c("02-Jan-2016","30-Jun-2016","07-Nov-2015","24-Mar-2019",
                          "04-Jul-2019","02-Jun-2017","10-Dec-2018"))
```

Comment: Not clear about the expected ouotput

Comment: What have you tried? You tagged `ggplot2`, so some research shows https://stackoverflow.com/q/26788049/3358272, [`gridExtra`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/tableGrob.html), and [`ggplot2` gantt charts](https://stats.andrewheiss.com/misc/gantt.html) as candidates.

Comment: The data is not reproducible as is; the `year` vector is shorter than the others.

Comment: @r2evans thanks a lot. I will look at the gantt chart.

Answer (score 2):

Here is something you might want to play around with:

```
library(ggplot2)

# May need to Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
dat1$start_date <- as.Date(dat1$start_date, "%d-%b-%Y")
dat1$end_date <- as.Date(dat1$end_date, "%d-%b-%Y")

ggplot(dat1) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = ani, xend = ani, y= start_date, yend = end_date), size = 10) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]