# Plotting the amount of times a value was present in a column in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, shiny, plotly

I'm building a Shiny application to create visualizations for output reports of a system that I have.

The report contains 3 fields I'm interested in: Address Code, Street Code and City Code.
The values of these fields are numeric codes which I have, the meanings of these codes is not important for the problem, I simply want to create a plot where I can see how many times was each code present for each of the columns (a separate plot for each field)

So for example, the DF looks like this

```
Address Code | Street Code | City Code
   100              100        30
   100              100        30
   0                 15        40
                               50     
   25                          0
```

As you can see, the value of the code can also be null.

And the output I expect from this would be something like a horizontal bar plot showing

The Y axis would be the codes themselves, and the X axis would be the amount of times they were observed
So following the mock table, I want this:

```
          ADDRESS CODES
100 --------------
75  -
50  -
25  -
0   -------

    0     1      2     3
```

I saw [here][1] a way to approach the issue, but I keep running into errors.

```
output$plot_levels <- plotly::renderPlotly({
        #loadData merely grabs the data and returns it as a data frame.
        #loadData uses fread to read the data from a file. It handles the null values as "".
        df <- loadData()
        df %>% 
            select(-`Address Code`) %>% 
            gather() %>% 
            #filter(`Address Code` != "") %>% 
            ggplot(aes(`Address Code`, ..count..)) + geom_col()
    })
```

I keep getting "ERROR: object 'Address Code' not found" in the app. The Address Code being referred to there is the one in the ggplot line.

So why is it saying that it doesn't exist? I already confirmed that the loadData method is reading the source file correctly, and the column name is indeed read as Address Code.
[1]: [Plot table objects with ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788049/plot-table-objects-with-ggplot/26801750)

Comment: `select(-\`Address Code\`)` result in there is no more `Address Code` in the dataset you you pass to ggplot. Remove that one line would get rid of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
#Code
df %>% pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  group_by(value) %>%
  summarise(N=n()) %>%
  mutate(value=factor(value,levels = unique(value),ordered = T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=value,y=N))+
  geom_col(fill='cyan3')+
  coord_flip()+
  theme_bw()
```

Output:

[image]

Or using `plotly`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
#Code
ggplotly(df %>% pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  group_by(value) %>%
  summarise(N=n()) %>%
  mutate(value=factor(value,levels = unique(value),ordered = T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=value,y=N))+
  geom_col(fill='cyan3')+
  coord_flip()+
  theme_bw())
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Address.Code = c(100L, 100L, 0L, 50L, 25L), Street.Code = c(100L, 
100L, 15L, NA, NA), City.Code = c(30L, 30L, 40L, NA, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Thank you, how does this code know which column to pick? I dont see it indicated anywhere

Comment: @ThePorcius Hi dear, well as all columns contain codes, I have set `everything()` if you need a specific column please tell me and I can re configure the code.

Comment: Well the full report has over 100 columns, so I would just like to grab the codes that im interested in and dynamically plot them. There's no need to rewrite the whole thing as Im sure your method will be very useful for people looking for something similar, which is the idea of Stackoverflow, but for my specific case I'd just like to know to replace that everything() for, say, Address Code

Comment: @ThePorcius In that case try this modification on pivoting `pivot_longer(Address Code)` using back ticks and then only that variable will be reshaped. Let me know if that works!