# How to turn a contingency table directly into a bar graph when using the base table function?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: Original Data][image: Input]

[image: Desired Output]

I am attempting to create a bar graph directly from a contingency table but I do not know of a function in ggplot2 that has such capability. My original data looks like this with 0s, 1s, and -1s representing categorical answers in the columns. The problem is that I do not know how to subgroup them by the unique values in each of the columns.

I am iterating across columns using this code and this is what I have so far.

for (x in colnames(df)){

bar_graph <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Variant, y=x, fill = df[[x]])) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "dodge")

}

Comment: Do you have the data, or only the contingency table downstream of the data? ggplot2 is designed to work with tidy (aka "long") data frames, so it'd probably be simpler to construct that from the data (e.g. `count(mtcars, gear, cyl) %>% ggplot...` than to convert a table into a data frame and then reshape it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788049/plot-table-objects-with-ggplot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may wish to create a separate table. Extract the legend as a separate `grob`  then lay out each part separately.

Sample code:

```
    library(grid)
    library(gridExtra)
    library(ggplot2)

  df1<-df %>%
      gather(name, value, `Yes`:`No`)   
    
    df1$name=factor(df1$name, levels=c("Yes", "No"))
      
      g_legend <- function(a.gplot){
        tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot))
        leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
        legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
        return(legend)}
    
    p = ggplot(df1, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=name) ) + 
      geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")+ 
      theme_bw()+
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1, face="bold", size=12, color="black"), 
            axis.title.x = element_blank(),
            axis.text.y = element_text( face="bold", size=12, color="black"),
            axis.title.y = element_blank(),
            strip.text = element_text(size=10, face="bold"),
            legend.position = "none",
            legend.title = element_blank(),
            legend.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 16,face="bold"))+
            scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1)))+
    ggtitle("Relationship between daily consumption of fruit/fruit juice and SNP AX")
    
    
    
    leg = g_legend(p)
    
    
    tab = t(df)
    tab = tableGrob(tab, rows=NULL, theme=ttheme_minimal(base_size = 16))
    tab$widths <- unit(rep(1/ncol(tab), ncol(tab)), "npc")
    
    grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(nullGrob(), 
                             p +  
                               theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
                                     axis.title.x=element_blank(),
                                     axis.ticks.x=element_blank()),
                             widths=c(1,8)), 
                arrangeGrob(arrangeGrob(nullGrob(),leg,heights=c(1,10)),
                                                    tab, nullGrob(), widths=c(6,20,1)), heights=c(4,1))
```

Plot:

[image]
Sample data:

```
df<-structure(list(variable = c("AA", "AB", "BB"), Yes = c(10, 50, 
90), No = c(80, 40, 10)), spec = structure(list(cols = list(variable = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Yes = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), No = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


df1<-structure(list(variable = c("AA", "AB", "BB", "AA", "AB", "BB"
), name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Yes", 
"No"), class = "factor"), value = c(10, 50, 90, 80, 40, 10)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer suggested how to build a bar plot *on top of* a contingency table. Here I propose how to build a bar plot *from* a contingency table.

The recommended workflow would be to build both the contingency table and the plot based on tidy data. Here's an example:

```
# [Case A] Both the contingency table and the plot are based on tidy data

# Data
df <- data.frame(variant = c(rep("AA", times = 10),
                             rep("AA", times = 80),
                             rep("AB", times = 50),
                             rep("AB", times = 40),
                             rep("BB", times = 90),
                             rep("BB", times = 10)),
                 fruit_daily = c(rep("yes", times = 10),
                                 rep("no", times = 80),
                                 rep("yes", times = 50),
                                 rep("no", times = 40),
                                 rep("yes", times = 90),
                                 rep("no", times = 10)))

# Contingency table
df |> 
  janitor::tabyl(fruit_daily, variant) 

# Bar plot (using relevel to maintain the bars ordered as in the question)
df |> 
  dplyr::mutate(fruit_daily = forcats::fct_relevel(fruit_daily, "yes", "no")) |>
  ggplot2::ggplot(aes(fill = fruit_daily, x = variant)) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge())
```

Yet, you *can* build a bar plot starting from a contingency table:

```
# [Case B] A bar plot from the contingency table using janitor::tabyl
df |> 
  janitor::tabyl(variant, fruit_daily) |>
  tidyr::gather(key = answers, value = how_many, no:yes) |>
  dplyr::mutate(answers = forcats::fct_relevel(answers, "yes", "no")) |>
  ggplot2::ggplot(aes(y = how_many, x = variant, fill = answers)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

Finally, the same task starting from the base table function (inspired by [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788049/plot-table-objects-with-ggplot)):

```
# [Case C] A bar plot from the contingency table using base table function
as.data.frame(table(df)) |>  
  dplyr::mutate(fruit_daily = forcats::fct_relevel(fruit_daily, "yes", "no")) |>
  ggplot2::ggplot(aes(y = Freq, x = variant, fill = fruit_daily)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```